# Javascript works great on localhost, doesn't work on server

Tags: javascript

I am perplexed about why my script works on my laptop but doesn't work when I put it up on the server:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <TITLE>Cubic Feet</TITLE>
    <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="text/javascript">


    function Calculate()
    {
        var qty1 = document.getElementById('q1').value;
        var len1 = document.getElementById('l1').value;
        var width1 = document.getElementById('w1').value;
        var height1 = document.getElementById('h1').value;
        var cube1 = (qty1*(len1*width1*height1))/1728;
        var ss1 = cube1/53.3;

        var qty2 = document.getElementById('q2').value;

        if (qty2 =="") {
            qty2=0
            cube2=0
            ss2=0;
        }

        var len2 = document.getElementById('l2').value;
        var width2 = document.getElementById('w2').value;
        var height2 = document.getElementById('h2').value;
        var cube2 = (qty2*(len2*width2*height2))/1728;
        var ss2 = cube2/53.3;

        var qty3 = document.getElementById('q3').value;

        if (qty3=="") {
            qty3=0;
            cube3=0;
            ss3=0;
        }

        var len3 = document.getElementById('l3').value;
        var width3 = document.getElementById('w3').value;
        var height3 = document.getElementById('h3').value;
        var cube3 = (qty3*(len3*width3*height3))/1728;
        var ss3 = cube3/53.3;  


        var totcube = cube1 + cube2 + cube3;
        var totskid = ss1 + ss2+ss3;
        var tq = parseInt(qty1) + parseInt(qty2)+parseInt(qty3);
        var trlft = totskid * 2;

        var form = document.forms[0];

        form.cuft1.value = cube1.toFixed(2);
        form.sk1.value = ss1.toFixed(1);
        form.cuft2.value = cube2.toFixed(2);
        form.sk2.value = ss2.toFixed(1);
        form.cuft3.value = cube4.toFixed(2);
        form.sk3.value = ss4.toFixed(1);


        form.totalcuft.value = totcube.toFixed(2); 
        form.sktotal.value = totskid.toFixed(1);
        form.totalqty.value = tq.toFixed(1);
        form.feet.value = trlft.toFixed(1);

    }

    function ClearForm(form)
    {
        form.q1.value = "";
        form.l1.value = "";
        form.w1.value = "";
        form.h1.value = "";
        form.cuft1.value = "";
        form.q2.value = "";
        form.l2.value = "";
        form.w2.value = "";
        form.h2.value = "";
        form.cuft2.value = "";
        form.q3.value = "";
        form.l3.value = "";
        form.w3.value = "";
        form.h3.value = "";
        form.cuft3.value = "";
        form.totalcuft.value = "";
        form.sktotal.value = "";
        form.totalqty.value = "";
        form.feet.value = "";
    }

    // end of JavaScript functions -->
    </SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<FORM NAME="Calculator" METHOD="post">

Enter the quantity (number of pieces, skids, boxes, whatever) and their dimensions (length, width, height) in INCHES, then click Calculate.

<P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Calculate" name="AddButton"  onClick="Calculate(this.form.q1.value, this.form.h1.value, this.form.w1.value, this.form.l1.value, this.form)">
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Clear" name="ClearButton" onClick="ClearForm(this.form)">

<p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td> Container 1 Qty <input type="TEXT" id="q1" value="" size="5"></td>
        <td> Length <input type="TEXT" id="l1" value="" size ="5"></td>
        <td> Width <input type="TEXT" id="w1" value="" size = "5"></td>
        <td> Height <input type="TEXT" id="h1" value="" size = "5"></td>
        <td> Cu.Ft. <input type="TEXT" id="cuft1" value="" size = "5"></td> 
        <td> Skid spots <input type="TEXT" id="sk1" value="" size ="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Container 2 Qty <input type="TEXT" id="q2" value="" size="5"></td>
        <td> Length <input type="TEXT" id="l2" value="" size="5"></td>
        <td> Width <input type="TEXT" id="w2" value="" size="5"></td>
        <td> Height <input type="TEXT" id="h2" value="" size="5"></td>
        <td> Cu.Ft. <input type="TEXT" id="cuft2" value="" size="5"></td>
        <td> Skid spots <input type="TEXT" id="sk2" value="" size="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Container 3 Qty <input type="TEXT" id="q3" value="" size="5"></td>
        <td> Length <input type="TEXT" id="l3" value="" size="5"></td>
        <td> Width <input type="TEXT" id="w3" value="" size="5"></td>
        <td> Height <input type="TEXT" id="h3" value="" size="5"></td>
        <td> Cu.Ft. <input type="TEXT" id="cuft3" value="" size="5"></td>
        <td> Skid spots <input type="TEXT" id="sk3" value="" size="5"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

        <td>Totals:</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td> Total Qty <input type="TEXT" id="totalqty" value="" size="5"></td>
        <td> Cu.Ft. <input type="TEXT" id="totalcuft" value="" size="5"></td>
        <td> Skid spots <input type="TEXT" id="sktotal" value="" size="5"></td>
        <td> Linear Feet <input type="TEXT" id="feet" value="" size="5"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

What could be causing it to not work on the server?

There's no error messages. Answers aren't being produced when I click calculate after I upload it onto the server. Works perfectly locally.

Thanks for having a look.

Comment: Works on server fine: http://jsfiddle.net/XMncS/.

Comment: Try adding a `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the very top. What browser are you testing this in anyways?

Comment: Firefox. I added your tag to my code and then tried with Mikhail's code and didn't work. Not sure how this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `cube4` with `cube3`, `ss4` with `ss3`, `text/javascript` with `javascript` and put `<!--` after `<SCRIPT>`.

Here is what you should get after these replacements:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Cubic Feet</TITLE>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="javascript">
<!--
function Calculate()
{
var qty1 = document.getElementById('q1').value;
var len1 = document.getElementById('l1').value;
var width1 = document.getElementById('w1').value;
var height1 = document.getElementById('h1').value;
var cube1 = (qty1*(len1*width1*height1))/1728;
var ss1 = cube1/53.3;

var qty2 = document.getElementById('q2').value;

if (qty2 =="") {
   qty2=0
   cube2=0
   ss2=0;
}

var len2 = document.getElementById('l2').value;
var width2 = document.getElementById('w2').value;
var height2 = document.getElementById('h2').value;
var cube2 = (qty2*(len2*width2*height2))/1728;
var ss2 = cube2/53.3;

var qty3 = document.getElementById('q3').value;

if (qty3=="") {
   qty3=0;
   cube3=0;
   ss3=0;
}

var len3 = document.getElementById('l3').value;
var width3 = document.getElementById('w3').value;
var height3 = document.getElementById('h3').value;
var cube3 = (qty3*(len3*width3*height3))/1728;
var ss3 = cube3/53.3;


var totcube = cube1 + cube2 + cube3;
var totskid = ss1 + ss2+ss3;
var tq = parseInt(qty1) + parseInt(qty2)+parseInt(qty3);
var trlft = totskid * 2;

var form = document.forms[0];

form.cuft1.value = cube1.toFixed(2);
form.sk1.value = ss1.toFixed(1);
form.cuft2.value = cube2.toFixed(2);
form.sk2.value = ss2.toFixed(1);
form.cuft3.value = cube3.toFixed(2);
form.sk3.value = ss3.toFixed(1);


form.totalcuft.value = totcube.toFixed(2);
form.sktotal.value = totskid.toFixed(1);
form.totalqty.value = tq.toFixed(1);
form.feet.value = trlft.toFixed(1);

}

function ClearForm(form)
{
form.q1.value = "";
form.l1.value = "";
form.w1.value = "";
form.h1.value = "";
form.cuft1.value = "";
form.q2.value = "";
form.l2.value = "";
form.w2.value = "";
form.h2.value = "";
form.cuft2.value = "";
form.q3.value = "";
form.l3.value = "";
form.w3.value = "";
form.h3.value = "";
form.cuft3.value = "";
form.totalcuft.value = "";
form.sktotal.value = "";
form.totalqty.value = "";
form.feet.value = "";
}

// end of JavaScript functions -->
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>

<BODY>

<FORM NAME="Calculator" METHOD="post">

Enter the quantity (number of pieces, skids, boxes, whatever) and their dimensions (length, width, height) in INCHES, then click Calculate.

<P><INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Calculate" name="AddButton"  onClick="Calculate(this.form.q1.value, this.form.h1.value, this.form.w1.value, this.form.l1.value, this.form)">
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Clear" name="ClearButton" onClick="ClearForm(this.form)">

<p>
<table>
<tr>
<td> Container 1 Qty <input type="TEXT" id="q1" value="" size="5"></td>
<td> Length <input type="TEXT" id="l1" value="" size ="5"></td>
<td> Width <input type="TEXT" id="w1" value="" size = "5"></td>
<td> Height <input type="TEXT" id="h1" value="" size = "5"></td>
<td> Cu.Ft. <input type="TEXT" id="cuft1" value="" size = "5"></td>
<td> Skid spots <input type="TEXT" id="sk1" value="" size ="5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Container 2 Qty <input type="TEXT" id="q2" value="" size="5"></td>
<td> Length <input type="TEXT" id="l2" value="" size="5"></td>
<td> Width <input type="TEXT" id="w2" value="" size="5"></td>
<td> Height <input type="TEXT" id="h2" value="" size="5"></td>
<td> Cu.Ft. <input type="TEXT" id="cuft2" value="" size="5"></td>
<td> Skid spots <input type="TEXT" id="sk2" value="" size="5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Container 3 Qty <input type="TEXT" id="q3" value="" size="5"></td>
<td> Length <input type="TEXT" id="l3" value="" size="5"></td>
<td> Width <input type="TEXT" id="w3" value="" size="5"></td>
<td> Height <input type="TEXT" id="h3" value="" size="5"></td>
<td> Cu.Ft. <input type="TEXT" id="cuft3" value="" size="5"></td>
<td> Skid spots <input type="TEXT" id="sk3" value="" size="5"></td>
</tr>
<tr>

<td>Totals:</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Total Qty <input type="TEXT" id="totalqty" value="" size="5"></td>
<td> Cu.Ft. <input type="TEXT" id="totalcuft" value="" size="5"></td>
<td> Skid spots <input type="TEXT" id="sktotal" value="" size="5"></td>
<td> Linear Feet <input type="TEXT" id="feet" value="" size="5"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

This works fine for me in Firefox.

Comment: Instead of using the `name` attribute for a `<script>` tag, maybe it should be changed to `type="text/javascript"`. I think `name` is deprecated or something

Comment: Well, made all changes and still stuck. I use Drupal and had put some code into an article with full html setting earlier and that was fine. However, when I use this script that works fine on my machine and uploaded it to my GoDaddy hosting account, it neither works as a HTML file (won't calculate on click) nor when put into a Drupal article with full html (same thing). (scratches head) :/ I'm also using Firefox. Tried clearing the cache in Drupal and that didn't resolve it. When I use Firebug, it thinks there is no javascript. :S

Comment: changed the one line per Ian's suggestion to type="text/javascript" and it works. (facepalm) Thanks Mikhail and Ian